# How to use part of a POST response as an argument for another post request? (pagination for GraphQL)

Tags: node.js, post, pagination, graphql

I want to do multiple POST request to the Github GraphQL API with pagination using 'endCursor'.

```
var unirest = require ('unirest');
var async = require('async');
const endpoint="https://api.github.com/graphql"
const token = "sometoken";

var search_query={
  "query": 'query($name: String!, $after: String){\
          search(query:$name, type: USER, first: 2, after: $after){\
                userCount\
                pageInfo{endCursor}\
                nodes{\
                   ...on User{\
                          id \
                          bio \
                          html_url:url \
                         }\
                       }\
                     }\
                   }',
     "variable": {"name":"somename", "after":null}
    };
unirest.post(endpoint)
.headers({"Content-Type": "text/html" , "Authorization": "bearer "+token, 'user-agent': 'node.js'})
.send(JSON.stringify(search_query)) //creating requests
.end(function(response, request){
    console.log(response.body.data.search.pageInfo.endCursor);
  });
```

I want to iterate this POST request for multiple times. Each time with the $after as the endCursor from last request. How would I do that? Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First i'd recommend you also fetch `hasNextPage` from pageInfo
so you could know when you reached the end.

After that you just need to structure your code better

change search_query to a function like so:

```js
function searchQuery(after = null) {
  return {
    "query": `query($name: String!, $after: String){
          search(query:$name, type: USER, first: 2, after: $after){
                userCount
                pageInfo {
                    hasNextPage
                    endCursor
                }
                nodes{
                   ...on User{
                          id 
                          bio 
                          html_url:url 
                         }
                       }
                     }
                 }`,
    "variable": {
      "name": "somename",
      "after": after
    }
  };
};
```

now `searchQuery` returns a query based on the parament `after` 
so what you need to do is create a logical `"while"` that will finish when the response `hasNextPage` is false:

```js
function queryServer(after) {
  unirest.post(endpoint)
    .headers({
      "Content-Type": "text/html",
      "Authorization": "bearer " + token,
      'user-agent': 'node.js'
    })
    .send(JSON.stringify(searchQuery(after))) //creating requests
    .end(function(response, request) {
      // do stuff with the result
      console.log(response.body.data.search.pageInfo.endCursor);
      
      // if there are more pages get them
      if (response.body.data.search.pageInfo.hasNextPage) {
        return queryServer(response.body.data.search.pageInfo.endCursor);
      }
    });
}

queryServer(null);
```

Note: i haven't tested the code, and IMO the code could be much cleaner with a different request package like [axios](https://github.com/axios/axios) that supports `promises`, and then you could even incorporate `async/await` so it would be much more simpler to use and understand
instead of that ugly recursion that is currently needed...

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer!  I've already looked into `Promise` and use that as part of my code. Your advice are much appreciated!

Comment: My pleasure, i'll appreciate if you can upvote this answer see https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers